# В кавычках или без пишется аббревиатура малоизвестной организации?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

Проверьте, пожалуйста, следующие предложения:

1. "ЗКЦИ" расшифровывается как "Защитники красивых цветочков от истребления".
2. ЗКЦИ спасло сегодня 8 васильков.
3. "Защитники красивых цветочков от истребления" спасли сегодня 8 васильков.

Дополнительный вопрос: глагол в предложении номер 3 должен быть в единственном или во множественном числе? Уточню, что с названиями спортивных команд, журналов и гос. учреждений я вроде бы разобралась. Интересует использование кавычек для названий малоизвестных организаций.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~1. В аббревиатуре кавычки не нужны.
~2. Тут скорее множественное число, если исходить из данной расшифровки.
~3. Кавычки, думаю, опциональны. Нужны только в том случае, если сия организация официально носит такое название.